# Dynamic cell value in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that generates a daily report based on the amount of people working. Based on some data, it gets a final value.

I want to create a macro that once clicked will compare that value to another value that is located in another spreadsheet. The formula I have so far is this:
    =IF(E7=[Test.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$15; "OK"; "Error").

This works fine. However, the value E7 is always going to be checked, but the value in test.xlsx B15 needs to be B16 tomorrow for example. How to get a dynamic reference logic inserted here? Can I use some kind of date changes to get the right cell address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind,
I have found a solution myself. The formula is

```
=IF(E7=OFFSET(Test.xlsx!Satnica;0;DAY(TODAY())); "OK"; "Error")
```

Satnica is actually a Defined Name for a cell that is just prior to the starting of all values.